# Docker service exits with exit code 0

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a Python Celery docker service that I'm trying to run, but it's exiting with status code 0, whether running the docker-compose command for all the services, or just for celery after the other 2 have started up.  If I go into my flask docker container and run the command in the command line, Celery does start up.

The sh fix_celery_naming.sh just fixes an issue with the naming in celery, which makes it incompatible with Python 3.7 and won't be ready until the next major release of Celery.

docker info

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 47
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.13.0-46-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 17.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 8.559GiB
Name: ubuntu
ID: NNOD:QGSH:B3HB:PTDT:Y5AG:D5XR:6NH4:CKZS:KV3R:FO3X:7Y3U:IUEN
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: jc
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        GRIP_ENVSET: ${GRIP_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ".:/code"
      - "/tmp:/tmp"
      # Mount the Docker socket so that other Docker images can be started up.
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    environment:
      - PORT=5000
      - GRIP_ENV=${GRIP_ENV}
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis
    # Access ports running on the host
    network_mode: host
    #links:
    #  - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    #restart: on-failure
    container_name: redis
    network_mode: host
    expose:
      - 6379
  celery:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    # TODO: Better support for handling Redis not being up yet. (e.g., install Dockerize)
    command: sh fix_celery_naming.sh && celery -A grip_server.celery worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - redis
    tty: true
```

docker-compose --verbose up celery

```
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
WARNING: compose.config.environment.__getitem__: The GRIP_ENV variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/jc/.docker/config.json', '/home/jc/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: /home/jc/.docker/config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.parse_auth: Found entry (registry='https://index.docker.io/v1/', username='jc')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/version HTTP/1.1" 200 543
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localhost
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': ''}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '18.06.1-ce', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.38', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2018-08-21T17:23:27.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': 'e68fc7a', 'GoVersion': 'go1.10.3', 'KernelVersion': '4.13.0-46-generic', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}], Version=18.06.1-ce, ApiVersion=1.38, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=e68fc7a, GoVersion=go1.10.3, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.13.0-46-generic, BuildTime=2018-08-21T17:23:27.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info <- ()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/info HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info -> {'Architecture': 'x86_64',
 'BridgeNfIp6tables': True,
 'BridgeNfIptables': True,
 'CPUSet': True,
 'CPUShares': True,
 'CgroupDriver': 'cgroupfs',
 'ClusterAdvertise': '',
 'ClusterStore': '',
 'ContainerdCommit': {'Expected': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e',
                      'ID': '468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e'},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-server', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 2 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('02d0e7592c5f1069c9085c7d5dc1e9a1c107af484161d2588296619661427e63')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/02d0e7592c5f1069c9085c7d5dc1e9a1c107af484161d2588296619661427e63/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': [],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['./start.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
            'Env': ['PORT=5000',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('30a3c78300fd6a51c294421050c7cfa1b9a140aaec1286b73390246e99fba2f1')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/30a3c78300fd6a51c294421050c7cfa1b9a140aaec1286b73390246e99fba2f1/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['redis-server'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['redis-server'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
            'Env': ['affinity:container==64ea18c780ef4cf166b202ed58decccc00ee967c19e52f915b5375b7c9f35799',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-server', 'com.docker.compose.service=redis', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dredis%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1334
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('30a3c78300fd6a51c294421050c7cfa1b9a140aaec1286b73390246e99fba2f1')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/30a3c78300fd6a51c294421050c7cfa1b9a140aaec1286b73390246e99fba2f1/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['redis-server'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['redis-server'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
            'Env': ['affinity:container==64ea18c780ef4cf166b202ed58decccc00ee967c19e52f915b5375b7c9f35799',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-server', 'com.docker.compose.service=celery', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dcelery%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1206
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['fix_celery_naming.sh',
          '&&',
          'celery',
          '-A',
          'grip_server.celery',
          'worker',
          '-l',
          'info'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('redis')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/images/redis/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['redis-server'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('grip-server_celery')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/images/grip-server_celery/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['./start.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-server', 'com.docker.compose.service=redis', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dredis%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1334
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('redis')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/images/redis/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['redis-server'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('30a3c78300fd6a51c294421050c7cfa1b9a140aaec1286b73390246e99fba2f1')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/30a3c78300fd6a51c294421050c7cfa1b9a140aaec1286b73390246e99fba2f1/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['redis-server'],
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['redis-server'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['docker-entrypoint.sh'],
            'Env': ['affinity:container==64ea18c780ef4cf166b202ed58decccc00ee967c19e52f915b5375b7c9f35799',
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-server', 'com.docker.compose.service=celery', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dcelery%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 1206
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('grip-server_celery')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/images/grip-server_celery/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': '',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['./start.sh'],
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': None,
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['fix_celery_naming.sh',
          '&&',
          'celery',
          '-A',
          'grip_server.celery',
          'worker',
          '-l',
          'info'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Service: redis>, <Service: celery>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: redis>
compose.service.execute_convergence_plan: redis is up-to-date
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: redis>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Service: celery>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Service: celery>
Starting grip-server_celery_1 ... 
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Container: grip-server_celery_1 (3a9ed0)>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Container: grip-server_celery_1 (3a9ed0)>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach <- ('3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc', stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc/attach?logs=0&stdout=1&stderr=1&stream=1 HTTP/1.1" 101 0
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker attach -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7f38db9b99b0>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start <- ('3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc/start HTTP/1.1" 204 0
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker start -> None
Starting grip-server_celery_1 ... done
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service: celery>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
Attaching to grip-server_celery_1
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <- (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=grip-server', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/events?filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dgrip-server%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7f38dba32710>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/containers/3a9ed0271c53166d7a968dfe1e362db75922d82b1bf66be029aa3fcb7c431cfc/wait HTTP/1.1" 200 30
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 0}
grip-server_celery_1 exited with code 0
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['fix_celery_naming.sh',
          '&&',
          'celery',
          '-A',
          'grip_server.celery',
          'worker',
          '-l',
          'info'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
...
```

Comment: What does the `-l` flag do for the celery command? I'm not seeing that as a valid arg

Comment: @C.Nivs, I'm not sure.  I copied that from an example, but it's probably just ignoring it.

Comment: With regard to `fix_celery_naming.sh`, is it necessary to run it in 3.7 or could you run it in 3.6? It seems like that's adding an unnecessary layer of complexity. Also, with regard to celery apps with flask, it's helpful to add a `network` to attach all of them to, that way you don't have to mount the `docker.sock` file

Comment: C.Nivs, We are trying to stick with 3.7.  I should have mentioned that I can start up Celery using the Docker command.  It's docker compose that's resulting in the 0 status code.  Also, I do have host network set yo.  docker.sock is only there to allow starting another docker container from inside of this container (starting it as a sibling).  That hasn't changed recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to use

```
bash -c "<command>"
```

to be able to execute multiple commands:

```
command: bash -c "sh fix_celery_naming.sh && celery -A components.grip_sim_server.server.celery worker"
```